# Biological Key for Yard Weeds?

Tags: species-identification, botany, taxonomy

I'm tinkering with an idea for an app to identify yard weeds, just as a personal project. I've been looking for some sort of dichotomous key (ie, "Does it have fur?" "Does it have feathers?" sort of thing), but so far everything I've found is just a list of pictures (ie Top 10 Yard Weeds in Southern US). Is anyone aware of an existing resource I could use?

Comment: The folks at Gardening and Landscaping SE might be more likely to know :)

Comment: You should check out the [Seek](https://www.inaturalist.org/pages/seek_app) app--point your phone camera at an organism (insect, plant, animal, fungus) near you and it'll give you an ID! I've used it for a few years, it's really cool, and mostly correct in my experience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend searching the following on your browser: 'plant species identification gov'.

Also here are some resources that you might find helpful: you can search for a common list of invasive plant species in your country (such lists are available on Wikipedia, [here is an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_invasive_species_in_Australia)), alternatively you could use a local government webpage to search and identify invasive plant species in your specific region.

Dichotomous keys can be found on botanical/herbarium/environmental government websites, [here is an example](https://www.qld.gov.au/environment/plants-animals/plants/herbarium/identify-specimens).

Lastly, apps like iNaturalist can identify plant species for you.

Comment: As it turns out, changing what I searched helped. Thank you!